# Extraer información de un archivo json especificando un valor

Tags: python, json, bash, jq

Tengo un archivo json con varios modulos iguales a este todos dentro de "results":

```
 [
         {
            "id": 143170,
            "type": "job_host_summary",
            "url": "/api/v2/job_host_summaries/143170/",
            "related": {
                "job": "/api/v2/jobs/147977/",
                "host": "/api/v2/hosts/19029/"
            },
            "summary_fields": {
                "host": {
                    "id": 19029,
                    "name": "wst",
                    "description": "wst"
                },
                "job": {
                    "id": 147977,
                    "name": "wst_upd_v1.6.0",
                    "description": "Actualiza wxt desde v1.5.2 a v.1.6.0",
                    "status": "failed",
                    "failed": true,
                    "elapsed": 1762.653,
                    "type": "job",
                    "job_template_id": 1358,
                    "job_template_name": "wst_upd_v1.6.0"
                }
            },
            "created": "2022-02-01T14:36:03.921804Z",
            "modified": "2022-02-01T14:36:03.921820Z",
            "job": 147977,
            "host": 19029,
            "host_name": "wst",
            "changed": 0,
            "dark": 0,
            "failures": 0,
            "ok": 7,
            "processed": 1,
            "skipped": 2,
            "failed": false,
            "ignored": 0,
            "rescued": 0
        },
```

Necesito que al encontrar esto: `wst_upd_v1.6.0` saber el valor de esto:

```
"failed": false (true).
```

Pero este valor esta repetido en todos los otros modulos del json.  La otra opción sería extraer en otro archivo el modulo que paso de ejemplo (pero solo ese que tiene la "palabra clave" `wst_upd_v1.6.0` )

Estoy ejecutando el siguiente comando:

```
cat archivo.json | jq '.results[] | {Puesto: .summary_fields.job} | select(.Puesto.job_template_name == "wst_upd_v1.6.0")'
```

detalle query:

```
.results[] | 
{Puesto: .summary_fields.job} | 
select(.Puesto.job_template_name == "wst_upd_v1.6.0")
```

me trae esta parte que solo me sirve para saber que existe pero no puedo obtener el valor "failed":. El valor failed que esta dentro de esto no me sirve ya que trae un valor distinto al que esta fuera.

```
{
  "Puesto": {
    "id": 147977,
    "name": "wst_upd_v1.6.0",
    "description": "Actualiza wxt desde v1.5.2 a v.1.6.0",
    "status": "failed",
    "failed": true,
    "elapsed": 1762.653,
    "type": "job",
    "job_template_id": 1358,
    "job_template_name": "wst_upd_v1.6.0"
  }
}
```

otra opción es ejecutar este comando:

```
cat archivo.json | jq '.results[]
```

y desde ahi recorrerlo y obtener el resultado que necesito.
Se les ocurre una forma de hacerlo usando bash o python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ jq '.results[] | select(.summary_fields.job.job_template_name =="wst_upd_v1.6.0").failed' results.json
```

detalle*

```
.results[] | 
select(.summary_fields.job.job_template_name =="wst_upd_v1.6.0").failed
```

del array formado por `.results` filtrar aquellos items que cumplan el select `.summary_fields.job.job_template_name =="wst_upd_v1.6.0"` de esos resultados retornar `.failed`

variantes: del array filtrar select filtrar campo(s)

```
.results[] | 
select(.summary_fields.job.job_template_name =="wst_upd_v1.6.0") | 
.failed
```

```
.results[] | 
select(.summary_fields.job.job_template_name =="wst_upd_v1.6.0") | 
[.id, .failed]
```

con argumentos para script

```
$ jq --arg nombre_template 'wst_upd_v1.6.0' '.results[] | select(.summary_fields.job.job_template_name == $nombre_template ) | .failed' results.json
```

Comment: Muchas gracias alo Malbarez!!!